# Understanding require in nodejs related to the AWS module

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm going through a project where in `app.js` the AWS module is required and its config is set via `AWS.config.update`. In a later file, AWS is required again but this time it uses the credentials set in the app.js file earlier. How does this work? I would have thought that we need to set the credentials again since the module is being re-imported in a different file.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see the project structure or files but here is what I am thinking:

app.js is run first (as I am guessing this is your index) and thats where the credentials are configured originally.
Then later, when you require the module again in a different point of the application, since app.js already executed at the start there is no need to reconfigure the AWS module as it already holds its present configuration.